# php - Need echo to evaluate variable twice. Grab variable name from mySQL database, then parse that variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have on one page:

```
  $cats=some_dynamic_data_value;

$sql="SELECT `number` FROM `table`";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$value=mysql_fetch_array($result);

        echo $value;
```

And in a mySQL database, I have $cats stored in a cell but also in other cells in the column `number` have regular old numbers in them, like 1, 2, 3.

When the echo evaluates, it only displays $cats,but I need it to display whatever $cats is defined to be at the time.

**Why won't the echo evaluate $cats again? How can I get it to evaluate the variable twice but still evaluate regular numbers? (Why double variables won't work)**

CHANGED TO BE MORE CLEAR I HOPE?

I FIURED IT OUT. USED EVAL FUNCTION.

Comment: I don't see where `$cats` is actually used anywhere besides the first line where it is assigned. Can you include your actual code?

Comment: _“I need it to display whatever $cats is defined to be at the time”_ – and what would that be f.e.?

Comment: $cats is stored in a cell in a mySQL table.

$value should evaluate to $cats and $cats should evaluate to whatever $cats is earlier defined as. $cats is a live statistic that is dynamically calculated.

Comment: @user2980927: that's great, but I don't see where it's actually used in your code sample above.

Comment: You don't use `$cats` in output. Try `print_r($cats);`

Comment: @Alexander He's saying that the value of `$value` is the string `'$cats'`.

Comment: Barmar, yes!

Alexander, I tried changing $cats in the table to print_r($cats); and it still did not parse. $value just showed print_r($cats);

Comment: @user2980927: that's not what Alexander meant. He meant to use `print_r($cats)` as a line in your PHP code.

Comment: What shows `var_dump($value);` instead of `echo $value;`?

Comment: I don't think we're on the same page here.

Comment: @user2980927: copy and paste `var_dump($value);` into your PHP file just above the `echo` statement and tell us what you see when you open the page in your browser.

Comment: All the answers provided will do exactly as you want, but something in your scenario always changes per answer which makes this such a complex thing, ever heard the saying FUBAR?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `eval` for this:

```
eval('echo "<td>" . ' . $value . ' . "</td>\n";');
```

I suggest you find a better way to do this, since `eval` will execute arbitrary PHP statements, not just expand variables.

Comment: Won't work because not all the values in the table are variables.

Some are just numbers that do not need to be parsed.

So in the table, sometimes I have a number stored, other times I have $cats stored and I have $cats dynamically calculated on each page.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that afterward. Variable variables expects `$value` to contain just `cats`, not `$cats`.

Comment: @user2980927: I highly suggest, at this point, that you find a different way to solve whatever problem you're trying to solve. If you start having to use eval and variable variables, you've got a giant mess on your hands and you won't be happy maintaining that code in 6 weeks, let alone 6 months.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but it's so dang close.

Basically I need a more flexible variable variable..

Comment: It seems like you're looking for a template system or CMS.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure I understand what you are after, but you can simply do this:

```
$cats=some_dynamic_data_value;

foreach ($row as $field=>$value) 
{
    echo "<td>" $cats ." - " . $value . "</td>\n";
};
```

Which will echo out the value in `$cats` inside your foreach statement - if that is what you mean by "defined at the time".

If on the other hand, if you have a bunch of other variables that `$cats` can be, you could look at a variable variables:

```
$dog="Woof";
$cow="Mooo";
$fluffeh="Fluffs";
```

Now, if you want to display the value of these, from your `$cats` variable at the time which contains the variable name, you can do so:

```
$cats="dog";

foreach ($row as $field=>$value) 
{
    echo "<td>" $$cats ." - " . $value . "</td>\n";
    // $value assumed to be 1234 for output.
};
```

Output:

```
<td>Woof - 1234
```

Comment: This won't work. In his case, the assignment would be `$cats='$dog';`

Comment: @Barmar Good lord, that just made variable variables even more horrible than it is normally - unless I write it, when it's fine of course and perfectly readable :P I would normally delete the answer, but in this case, it might be of use to the next visitor though not the actual person asking this one.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this will be work. Try to change value in database from "$cat" to "cat". Then you can use it in symbolic link:

```
$cats = "Hello from cats"; // somewhere a variable
$value = "cats"; // this value from database
echo $$value;
```

Comment: Yeah but then if I don't have the value stored as a variable, it displays incorrectly.

In the column `numbers` I am trying to store both variable names and static values.

Comment: @user2980927: if you have a way of knowing whether it's a variable, use that as a condition in an if-statement to determine whether to do the double-variable or just a regular echo.

Comment: Seems to be my best shot... Hmm